# Is it possible to create an object/class/interface that represents a signature of a function?

Tags: typescript, arrow-functions

Everything already works as expected in my code. What I'm wanting is to make it verbose, making the method signatures more self explanatory (I know I can use Doc comments for this, but I'd also like to use the **TypeScript** types) and can be better validated by [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/), for example.

Today I have this:

```
class Test{
    testMetadada<T>(expression: (t: T) => void) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The `expression` object is of type `(t: T) => void`, which is not very explanatory, I would like something like:

```
class Expression<T> extends (t: T) => void{

}
```

or

```
interface Expression<T> extends (t: T) => void{

}
```

or

```
let Expression = ((t: T) => void)<T>;
```

So that my method was something like:

```
class Test{
    testMetadada<T>(expression: Expression) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Where `Expression` represents the function `(t: T) => void`.

There anything I can do in this way?

> See [here the example of what I'm trying to implement with this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Class1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Class2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clazz1%3A%20Class1%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Class3%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop3%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clazz2%3A%20Class2%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20testMetadada%3CT%3E(expression%3A%20(t%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.getPropertiesByExpression(expression))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20getPropertiesByExpression(expression%3A%20(x)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20strAfterReturn%20%3D%20expression.toString().split(%22return%22)%5B1%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20strBeforeSemicon%20%3D%20strAfterReturn.split(%22%3B%22)%5B0%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20propertiesReferences%20%3D%20strBeforeSemicon.split(%22.%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20propertiesReferences.shift()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20propertiesReferences%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass1%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.prop1)%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass2%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.clazz1.prop1)%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass3%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.clazz2.clazz1.prop1)%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass3%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.clazz2.prop2)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20h1%20%3D%20document.createElement('h1')%3B%0D%0Ah1.textContent%20%3D%20%22See%20console!%20%3AD%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(h1)%3B) (the possibility of using [**`Arrow function`** of **TypeScript**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) as expressions [**Lambda Expressions C#**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) for metadata)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes using type aliases

`type Expression<T> = (t: T) => void`

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

And in your class...

```
class Test {

    testMetadada<T>(expression: Expression<T>) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

> [Example updated with solution](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Class1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop1%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Class2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop2%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clazz1%3A%20Class1%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Class3%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop3%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clazz2%3A%20Class2%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Expression%3CT%3E%20%3D%20(t%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20testMetadada%3CT%3E(expression%3A%20Expression%3CT%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.getPropertiesByExpression(expression))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20getPropertiesByExpression%3CT%3E(expression%3A%20Expression%3CT%3E)%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20strAfterReturn%20%3D%20expression.toString().split(%22return%22)%5B1%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20strBeforeSemicon%20%3D%20strAfterReturn.split(%22%3B%22)%5B0%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20propertiesReferences%20%3D%20strBeforeSemicon.split(%22.%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20propertiesReferences.shift()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20propertiesReferences%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass1%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.prop1)%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass2%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.clazz1.prop1)%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass3%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.clazz2.clazz1.prop1)%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass3%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.clazz2.prop2)%3B%0D%0Atest.testMetadada%3CClass3%3E(x%20%3D%3E%20x.clazz2.clazz1)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20h1%20%3D%20document.createElement('h1')%3B%0D%0Ah1.textContent%20%3D%20%22See%20console!%20%3AD%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(h1)%3B)